# Strange internet issues

Tags: networking, linux, internet

When I try and use any form of the internet, such as, apt-get, npm, the browser itself, etc, it hangs and cannot connect. 
However, when I ping, it can resolve hostnames and gets replies!

I can SSH to it from inside the local network too.

I've been having this issue and I can't find the solution anywhere!

I'm using the RPi B+ Model 1 if that helps

Comment: Can we see error messages and the output of `ifconfig` and `netstat -rn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time I have read about anybody having those kinds of errors the solution seems always to be to start with a fresh new copy of Raspian.

But there is a better solution:

To protect against wierdnesses like this I use Win32DiskImager to save .img files periodically when the system is running correctly.  That way I can always restore my system back to a known good condition.  I name the image files with the date, i.e.   2016-09-29.img

This way it restores any customization I have made so I do not need to start fresh and try to remember everything I have done with the system since the original install.